# Which among A, K, Q, J, 10 and A, 2, 3, 4, 5 of different suite is higher in Texas hold'em poker

Tags: texas-hold-em, straight

A2345 (different suits) is a straight and I have doubt whether AKQJ10 (different suit) can also be called as a straight or not. If both are straights then which one is higher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking about straights AKQJ10 is always higher and the lowest is A2345, Ace loses its value in straight if its not a member of AKQJ10. For eg KQJ109 is higher than A2345 when comparing straights because when we try comparing them in terms of high card ranking an Ace will always be higher than King but not in case of straights. Consider A as 1 in case of straights if we are not talking about AKQJ10.

> The highest possible Straight is A-K-Q-J-10 (also called “Broadway”).
>   Straight combinations go all the way down to A-2-3-4-5, which is known
>   as the “Wheel” or “Bicycle”, in poker lingo. So the straight series goes like:
>
> ```
> A-K-Q-J-10
> K-Q-J-10-9
> Q-J-10-9-8
> J-10-9-8-7
> 10-9-8-7-6
> 9-8-7-6-5
> 8-7-6-5-4
> 7-6-5-4-3
> 6-5-4-3-2
> 5-4-3-2-A
> ```

Comment: Yes, a wheel is the lowest straight in ll poker games--except Pai Gow Poker as played in Nevada, where a wheel beats a K-high but loses to a Broadway.